# Radio button REQUIRED if input field has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a a reasonably quick problem to solve (I think). I have a form online and it validates the required content for the user's data, but has no validation on the first part of the form.

I've been asked however if I can make a radio button REQUIRED depending on whether an input field has been filled in.

The form can be found here:
http://www.elcorteingles.pt/reservas/livros_escolares/form.asp

So if the person start's filling in the input fields on the first line, that the radio buttons in the group become REQUIRED (for either the CDROM ou CADERNO but not both)

Comment: `$('#radiobutton').prop('required', $('#input').val().length > 0);`

Comment: This should be posted as an answer and should be accepted
(Adding a focusout event for sure)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `focusout` and `blur` events for the `input`:

```
$(function () {
    // Handle every input type text.
    // To select specific inputs, give them a common class and change the
    // selector accordingly. 
    $("input[type=text]").on("focusout blur", function () {
        // Check for inputs with class radio_btns which are in
        // the parent element (li).
        // Set their required property. 
        $(this).parent().find("input.radio_btns")
            .prop("required", $(this).val().trim().length > 0);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Yj6/2/)

[jQuery reference (Tree Traversal)](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

[jQuery reference (.prop())](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[jQuery reference (.focusout())](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

[jQuery reference (.blur())](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Answer (score -1):

**Try using the following js code its working:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".titulo_books").each(function(){
      $(this).focus(function(){
        var radioChecked=0;
        var currElemId = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        var radioSelecterId = (currElemId>9)  ? currElemId : "0"+currElemId;
        $("input:radio[name="+radioSelecterId+"caderno]").each(function(){
        if(radioChecked==0)
        {
         radioChecked==1;
          $(this).attr("checked","checked");
        }
        });


      });
    });

});
```

I have checked it by executing this from console on your site and it seems to work fine. You can alter this in the way you want. I have checked one of the four available radio button. User can change the input value if required. Or you can also change the default radio button selected through my code.

Comment: This code seem to be doing what I need. Instead of it selecting a radio button for the user, I want to add a simple DIV with a message asking the user to fill in one of the radio options and make sure the form can't be sent if they don't fill something in.

I've tried changing the last part to:

`if(radioChecked==0)
{
  $('<p class="error_message">Error!!!</p>').insertAfter('.corner_number_books');
}
else{
  $('.error_message').remove();
}`

But obviously it's now adding the error message to all the DIVs at once and the message doesn't dissapear if select a radio...

Answer (score -1):

This will work. You can include the following JQuery code in the script tag, and also the JQuery cdn link in the head tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#01titulo').focusout(function(){
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
           $('[name="01caderno"]').prop('required', true);
        } else {                          
            $('[name="01caderno"]').prop('required', false);
        }
        alert($('[name="01caderno"]').attr('required'));
    });
});
```